# php changing the width of a table column

Tags: php

Having a few issues with changing my column width and changing it through

```
colspan='2'
```

works up till my while loop where it throws the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ',' or ';'
```

Any help, heres my code:

```
echo "<table border='0', width='100%'><tr><th colspan='2'>ID</th>
                     <th colspan='2'>First Name</th>                             
                     <th colspan='2'>Last Name</th><th colspan='2'>Location</th>
                     <th colspan='2'>Last Updated</th></tr>";
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

        echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" .$row['userID'].' </td><td colspan='2'> '.$row['first_name'].' </td><td colspan='2'> '
        .$row['last_name'].' </td><td colspan='2'> '.$row['current_location'].' </td><td colspan='2'> '
        .$row['last_updated']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "</td><tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Not sure if that will solve anything, but you've got a comma where it's not needed on line 1 : border='0', width='100%'

Comment: You're using single quote as the delimiter around the strings and also the delimiter around the `colspan='2'` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are doing wrong concatenation

paste this inside while loop:

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" .$row['userID']." </td><td colspan='2'> ".$row['first_name']." </td><td colspan='2'> "
        .$row['last_name']." </td><td colspan='2'> ".$row['current_location']." </td><td colspan='2'> "
        .$row['last_updated']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "</td><tr>";
```

or

Simply use

```
<tr>
<td colspan='2'><?php echo $row['userID'];?>
<td colspan='2'><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
<td colspan='2'><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
<td colspan='2'><?php echo $row['current_location'];?></td>
<td colspan='2'><?php echo $row['last_updated']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?></td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the same quotes as the delimiters around the PHP strings and around the attribute values inside the string, e.g.:

```
' </td><td colspan='2'> '
```

Change one of them to double quotes:

```
' </td><td colspan="2"> '
```

or

```
" </td><td colspan='2'> "
```

Or escape the quotes inside:

```
' </td><td colspan=\'2\'> '
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to your concatenation You are using single quotes for both string and colspan attribute inside your loop

```
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
 {

    echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>" .$row['userID']." </td><td colspan='2'> 
   ".$row['first_name']." </td><td colspan='2'> "
   .$row['last_name']." </td><td colspan='2'> ".$row['current_location']." 
  </td><td colspan='2'> "
.$row['last_updated']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "</td><tr>";
```

}

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time, thanks this was the problem!